# Android: Reverse Geocoding not working

Tags: android, gps, reverse-geocoding

Apparently, I can get the latitude and longitude but when I this part of code below for Reverse Geocoding it shows as "Service not available". What does it mean? I have added user permisions for INTERNET, FINE and COARSE location in the Android manifest file. Am I missing something ?

Comment: can you upload the code ? with error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this comes when you are running your app on emulator, try running on actual device. I think it will work properly on device.

Comment: cool.. actually I faced this issue while running on google api emulator.. searched on internet and found that it happens on emulator but not device..and that was happening in my case.

Comment: I'm unable to get address for India only. Do you have any idea why this is happening? For other countries it shows the address.

Comment: well I placed editText below my map for user input(e.g city name place name etc.).. and passed that text in getFromLocationName(). Then using Address class I am extracting lat, long for the text and it is giving me the lat, long for India.

Comment: I cannot ask for a user input. I'm mandated to detect the user location. It's a part of the client requirement.